# Date literals in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, eclipselink, jpql

I wonder how to use date literals in Hibernate query language. I did as follows in my JPA project (as Eclipselink the provider) and it works.

```
SELECT m FROM Me m WHERE m.dob <= {d '1984-10-06'}
```

But this does not work when I change Hibernate (V 3.6.7) as the provider for my JPA project.

Comment: What you quote there is valid JPA syntax (see JPA2 spec section 4.6.1 - "JDBC escape syntax"). If Hibernate doesn't support it then its a bug in Hibernate, and should be raised as that.

Comment: @DataNucleus I agree with you. According to Hibernate's promise to support JPA, they must support this syntax. But Hibernate seems to support the date literal as 'yyyy-mm-dd' instead of {d 'yyyy-mm-dd'}

Comment: We are using Hibernate **V3.6.8** in a project and this valid JPA syntax doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions) says:

> Expressions used in the where clause include the following:
>   [...]
>
> - SQL literals 'foo', 69, 6.66E+2, '1970-01-01 10:00:01.0'

Comment: Using date literal as 'yyyy-mm-dd' works for me (but this is a non standard way)