# Timestamp literal in JPQL typed query with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Is there a way to use timestamp literals in JPQL queries with Hibernate?

There is a constant timestamp to compare to which should be placed in JPQL query.
Now it works this way

```
TypedQuery<TestEntity> query = entityManager
.createQuery("select t from TestEntity t where greatest(nvl(t.f1, :nullDate), nvl(t.f2, :nullDate)) between :date1 and :date2")
.setParameter("date1", date1)
.setParameter("date2", date2)
.setParameter("nulllDate", LocalDateTime.of(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

I've tried (solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672342/date-literals-in-hibernate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386109/jpa-date-literal)) to change the query to the following

```
select t from TestEntity t where greatest(nvl(t.f1, {ts '1970-01-01 00:00:00:000000001'}), nvl(t.f2, {ts '1970-01-01 00:00:00:000000001'})) between :startChanges and :endChanges
```

but got an error in runtime

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '{' [select t from TestEntity t where greatest(nvl(t.f1, {ts '1970-01-01 00:00:00:000000001'}), nvl(t.f2, {ts '1970-01-01 00:00:00:000000001'})) between :startChanges and :endChanges]
```

My setup is
Java 8
JPA 2.1
Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE
Hibernate 5.1.0.Final (reproduced also with 5.2.16.Final)
Oracle 11.2

**UPD:** maybe it's not on the spec, but greatest/nvl functions are passed from JPQL to SQL correctly with the code above. I've tried to wrap `greatest`/`nvl` in `function` but the literals are still not accepted.

Comment: Where does the JPA spec define a JPQL function of `greatest` ? or `nvl`? Answer : it doesn't

Comment: @DN1 I've replaced the query string with a more strict JPQL calling greatest/nvl via "function", but it doesn't change anything. It still accepts parameter and generates the same SQL for it while throwing an `unexpected char: '{'` error for literal.
`select t from TestEntity t where function('greatest', function('nvl', t.f1, {ts '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001'}), function('nvl', t.f2, {ts '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001'})) between :startChanges and :endChanges`

Comment: I can use JDBC escape syntax (what you're using with the curly brackets and "ts") with no issue with my JPA provider (and your syntax usage is valid IMHO), as per http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#jpql_literals  Maybe try a simple query without the function calls, and with the JDBC escape syntax to check that your JPA provider handles it correctly first, then add in the FUNCTIONs.

Comment: @DN1 I've tried a very basic query with no conditions but one with the literal. It results in the same error, looks like Hibernate 5.1.0 doesn't support timestamp literals, at least with this syntax. This was an issue for earlier versions at least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386109/jpa-date-literal#comment39230541_8386606

Comment: sounds like you need to raise a bug on them

Comment: @DN1 maybe this one is related https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8653

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a test in my enviroment, and this returns results:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date1);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

date1 = calendar.getTime();

calendar.setTime(date2);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

date2 = calendar.getTime();

TypedQuery<TestEntity> query = entityManager
.createQuery("select t from TestEntity t where greatest(nvl(t.f1, TO_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00,000000001', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9')), nvl(t.f2, TO_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00,000000001', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9')) between :date1 and :date2")
.setParameter("date1", date1)
.setParameter("date2", date2);
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

**EDIT:** Modified query to add `TO_TIMESTAMP` function. Confirmed by @dfche it is working

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works for me, too. But I'm trying to avoid setting nullDate as parameter and use inline literal instead.

Comment: Do you want to use string literal or a class?

Comment: string literal (with no parameter binding for nullDate)

Comment: I have edited to add literal string: `setParameter("nulllDate", "1970/01/01 00:00:00,000000000")`. Note: your parameter is `nulllDate` (3 lll), and your jpql have 2 (nullDate)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid setParameter at all, using literals in JPQL like this `greatest(nvl(t.f1, {ts '1970-01-01 00:00:00:000000001'})`, see the original post.

Comment: Try with `greatest(nvl(t.f1, TO_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00,000000001', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9'))`

Comment: @Alberto, TO_TIMESTAMP is invalid JPQL, please read a JPA manual. That JPA manual would tell you that a "timestamp literal" of the form being used is totally valid, and this JPA provider doesn't like it

Comment: This worked for me: `String consulta = "SELECT e FROM ExcepcionHistorico e WHERE greatest(nvl(tim_procx, TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00,000000001', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9')), nvl(tim_recept, TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 00:00:00,000000001', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9'))) BETWEEN :date3 and :date4";`. Result: `Hibernate: select <fields> where greatest(nvl(excepcionh0_.tim_procx, TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00,000000001', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9')), nvl(excepcionh0_.tim_recept, TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 00:00:00,000000001', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9'))) between ? and ?`

Comment: @Alberto `TO_TIMESTAMP` works fine, thanks. According to my (very brief) tests there is no performance difference between these 2 forms (`TIMESTAMP`/`TO_TIMESTAMP`) in terms of native SQL selects.

Comment: @dfche I'm glad to hear that and to have helped.

Comment: @DN1 looks like Hibernate passes some Oracle functions like `GREATEST`/`NVL`/`TO_TIMESTAMP` from JPQL to the resulting SQL as is, so it all works.