# Hibernate query to Get one hour back rows from oracle table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get the rows created/modified one hour back by using the following SQL query for oracle database

select * from filecontent where row_mod_dt <= sysdate-1/24 order by row_mod_dt desc;

I am trying to implement the same in our java application by using the following hibernate named query

@NamedQuery(name="FileContent.findsent",query="select id from filecontent c where c.rowmoddt <= current_date - 1/24")

But it is not giving the expected data.

Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Comment: "It is not giving expected data". So debug it by looking in the JPA provider log for what SQL was issued, and then you have your answer. Nobody here knows what your class looks like. "current_date" is a Date, so doing a subtraction is unlikely to give what you think. Why not format your post too, so it is readable

Comment: Thank you for your response.Sorry, if my post is not in a readable format. I am  new to stack over flow and JPA/hibernate.                                                                         The log is showing the sql statement as                                                     select fileconten0_.ID as col_0_0_  from FILECONTENT fileconten0_ cross where fileconten0_.ROW_MOD_DT<=current_date - (1/24).           
I am getting all rows as output. But i should get 1 hour back rows only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this as suggested in the post

[Performing Date/Time Math In HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639522/performing-date-time-math-in-hql)

changed the query as 
`@NamedQuery(name="FileContent.findsent",query="select id from filecontent c where c.rowmoddt <= :requiredTime")`

while setting the parameter, the java code is mentioned below.

```
Date in = new Date();
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(in.toInstant(), 
ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusHours(1);
Date out = Date.from(ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

query.setParameter("requiredTimeStamp",out, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

It may help others. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you must use the identification variable `c` to refer to entity attributes ... and the entity name in the from not the table: 
`query="select c from YourEntityName c where c.rowmoddt <= current_date - 1/24 orderby c.rowmoddt desc"`

Comment: Thank you for your response. i am using the entity attributes and entity name only. The query should give one hour back rows but it is giving all the rows means it is giving the latest rows also.

Comment: you can use `current_date - {t '01-00-00'}` .. this is the format of time literal in jpa ... but I am not sure if hibernate supports it or no

Comment: check this .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672342/date-literals-in-hibernate